# OpenMP for loop with specific threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new in parallel programming. I'm trying to make point cloud processing process parallel. I share with my program structure below. Firstly, I separate the point cloud into the partial clouds. My aim is that every thread must call the fillFrustumCloud() function separately.

```
int num_threads = 12;

std::vector<CloudColored::Ptr> vector_colored_projected_clouds(num_threads);
std::vector<Cloud::Ptr> vector_projected_clouds(num_threads);

omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

// private( ) shared()
#pragma omp parallel  shared(vector_colored_projected_clouds,vector_projected_clouds)
{
    
    for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
    {

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            std::cout << "Thread id: " << omp_get_thread_num() << " loop id: " << i <<  std::endl;
        }

        const unsigned int  start_index = cloud_in->size()/num_threads*i;
        const unsigned int  end_index = cloud_in->size()/num_threads*(i+1);

        Cloud::Ptr partial_cloud(new Cloud);

        if(i==num_threads-1)
        {
            partial_cloud->points.assign(cloud_in->points.begin()+start_index, cloud_in->points.end());
        }else{
            partial_cloud->points.assign(cloud_in->points.begin()+start_index, cloud_in->points.begin()+end_index);
        }

            LidcamHelpers::fillFrustumCloud(partial_cloud, mat_point_transformer, img_size, vector_colored_projected_clouds,
                                            vector_projected_clouds, i, interested_detections, id, reshaped_img);
    }
}
```

but output is:

```
Thread id: 0 loop id: 0
Thread id: 1 loop id: 0
Thread id: 2 loop id: 0
Thread id: 3 loop id: 0
Thread id: 0 loop id: 1
Thread id: 1 loop id: 1
Thread id: 2 loop id: 1
Thread id: 3 loop id: 1
Thread id: 0 loop id: 2
Thread id: 3 loop id: 2
Thread id: 2 loop id: 2
Thread id: 1 loop id: 2
Thread id: 3 loop id: 3
Thread id: 1 loop id: 3
Thread id: 2 loop id: 3
Thread id: 0 loop id: 3
```

According to my aim, it should be like this:

```
Thread id: 0 loop id: 0
Thread id: 1 loop id: 1
Thread id: 2 loop id: 2
```

Note that: I pass the vector_colored_projected_clouds and vector_projected_clouds into the function by reference in order to store the result. I guess they should be shared variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `#pragma omp parallel` constructor will create a parallel region, with as many threads as you have set it up. Hence, when you do:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
    {
       ... 
    }
}
```

every thread in the parallel region will execute all the iterations of the loop. That is why you have 16 outputted lines (*i.e.,* 4 threads x 4 loop iterations).

If you want to distribute the iterations of a loop among threads you should use the `#pragma omp for` instead. So in your code you can either do:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
    {
       ... 
    }
}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
{
   ... 
}
```

Since, you only want to distribute the iterations of the loop among threads, you can use the latter (*i.e.,* `#pragma omp parallel for`).

It looks as though you are using

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    std::cout << "Thread id: " << omp_get_thread_num() << " loop id: " << i <<  std::endl;
}
```

for debugging purposes. Bear in mind, however, that even with the `critical` region, the order in which threads will output is non-deterministic. If you rather that threads would output deterministically, use `#pragma omp ordered` instead of critical. The `ordered` constructor will enforce that the chunk of code that it wraps around will be executed in the same order that would have been executed if the code was executed sequentially.